# Enterprise Library 6.0 logging is creating a lot of log files with guid prefix

Tags: enterprise-library

I have UI, WCF and Workflow projects and each has a separate file to write the log. I changed autoFlush to false but it didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a concurrency issue. It will do that if it can't get a write lock on the file. Instead of failing, it will create a new guid prefixed file name.

Do you have multiple apps or multiple worker processes writing to the same file?

Comment: Yes I have three apps but they all share the same app pool.

Comment: that means they'll share the same w3wp, but doesn't prevent multiple instances of EntLib trying to concurrently write to the file. They don't share AppDomains

Comment: Also if you have a web garden, there could even be multiple processes